# Accessing values inside single array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have wasted two days on this and I can't take it anymore. I am getting well formed JSON data from my `$.ajax` call. Sample below...

```
"results":[
"{"a":"data","b":"data","c":"data","d":"data"}",
"{"a":"data","b":"data","c":"data","d":"data"}",
"{"a":"data","b":"data","c":"data","d":"data"}",
"{"a":"data","b":"data","c":"data","d":"data"}"
]
```

I have attempted to access the values in this single array of JSON objects and just can't figure it out. Here's my code below...

```
success:function (data) {

/*
$.each(data.results, function(i, val) {
console.log(i, val);
});
*/

$('a.previewUrl').each(function (i) {
    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data.results[0]);
    var previewUrl = $(this);
if(previewUrl.attr("href") == '') {
    previewUrl.attr("href", res[i].d);
}

});

} // end success
```

The `console.log` iteration over each JSON object in the array prints out fine but I think I have tried a dozen different ways to grab these values in the `$.each()` loop. What I am missing?

Comment: That doesn't look like well-formed JSON?  What's with all the extra quotes?

Comment: Hmmm... Shouldn't `data.results[0]` be `data.results[i]`, and `res[i]` to `res`? Since you are iterating over an array of strings? Also, your json strings looks a bit odd, your quotes aren't escaped. And, why do you have json strings, inside of a json string?

Comment: OMG. Kevin B is right. Two days of looking at this code and I didn't even notice they were JSON strings inside of another JSON string. Thank you, Kevin B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Json isn't valid. Try putting it through [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) and see what happens.

I think this could be what you were aiming for:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "a": "data",
        "b": "data",
        "c": "data"
    },
    {
        "a": "data",
        "b": "data",
        "c": "data"
    },
    {
        "a": "data",
        "b": "data",
        "c": "data"
    },
    {
        "a": "data",
        "b": "data",
        "c": "data"
    }
]}
```

and if you're using jQuery's $.getJSON function, you don't need to parse your data or if you're using the $.ajax function, set the datatype to json so it wil parse the data for you.